# Acronyms not showing

Tags: glossaries, texstudio, acronyms

Working on my thesis report using TeXStudio on Ubuntu 16.04. I am using the same code as in this [link](https://fr.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) for acronyms.
A trace of my code looks like this :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\input{acronyms.tex}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
        
    \clearpage
    \section{Introduction}

    \input{introduction}
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    \section{State of the art}

    \input{stateofart}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \section{Research Challenges}

    \input{challenges}
    \newpage
    \section*{References}
    \input{references}
    \clearpage
    
    \printacronyms
    
\end{document}
```

When compiling and building the whole file at the end it does not display the list of acronyms. I am wondering if any one have already faced the same issue and how did overcome it.

Will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the link @Stefan Pinnow. The thing is that the list of acronyms is not printed. Do you have a suggestion on how to make it work ? I have looked at different similar issues related to acronyms here but I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @user2567806: Do you have understood Stefan Pinnow's comment? Please reduce your document to the absolute minimal version that still do have the acronym list printed. There is no information about `acronyms.tex` and there is no `\makeglossaries` command at all (unless it is in the unavailable `acronyms.tex` file). Are you using the `makeglossaries` script at all?

Comment: Try `\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries}` and make sure you've used commands like `\gls` or `\glsadd`

Comment: There's a MWE for acronyms [`mwe-acr.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/mwe-acr.tex) provided with the `glossaries` package. Start with that and see if you can get the list of acronyms to appear.

Comment: sorry guys for my late reply. I finally have understood his comment :). I am not allowed to put the whole document as there is some classified infos so I did not measure the importance of putting it as I am using the same code for acronyms as in the link I have included. Sorry about that. I will try your suggestions and let you know about the outcome guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the previous comments, you really need to provide an MWE.

However, lacking an MWE, I think you need to add `\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]` just before `\printacronyms`. You will also need to add `\makenoidxglossaries` after `\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}`. This is described in the glossaries documentation, pp. 69 - 70.

Here's my MWE showing it working:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{GNU}       {GNU}        {GNU's Not Unix}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \gls{GNU} is the BEST!
    \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
    \printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Comment: it worked for me with your code finally ! Thank you guys all.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed your instructions and it didn't work at first. Two things that in the end made it work:

1. put the acronyms or acronym file in the preamble
2. if, like me, you've started by writing your document and now realize you need to add this list (so you haven't used them in your text), there is a `\glsaddall` command.